# Facebook Login doesn't fetching all User's profile information in swift

Tags: ios, swift

In my app I implemented FacebookLogin accessing permissions:

```
let facebookReadPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
```

Once all permissions granted, I am calling graph API for fetching user's profile info using:

```
let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)
```

It is returning just two values: `{ id = 86160953055XXXX; name = "Devendranath Reddy"; }`

I want Address, email, phone, first and last names also.

What is wrong here.

I even enabled for live access in developer.apple.com -> MyApp -> Settings

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

try this out, you need to set the parameters value:

so for Swift it would be this:

```
 parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name"}
```

In swift it would be something similar

something like this:

```
 let params = ["fields": "email, friends"]
```

so:

```
let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: params)
```

Add whatever fields you want to add, like "first_name" "last_name" etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

let params = ["fields": "email, first_name, gender, last_name, location"]

```
    let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: params)
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler(
        {
            (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if ((error) != nil)
            {
                // Failure code goes here.               
            }
            else
            {                                        
                // Success code goes here
                println("User Name is: \(userName)")
                println("User Email is: \(userMail)")
                println("Gender is: \(gender)")
            }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

This request won't grab all the information until your app is reviewed by Facebook's app review. It will only give you access to the public profile info, regardless of what permissions the user accepts.